# Minhag of reciting Tikkun Chatzot during the daytime?

Tags: minhag, three-weeks, daytime, tikkun-chatzot

I have heard, offhandedly, that there is supposedly a minhag to recite *Tikkun Chatzot* at/after mid*day* during the 3 weeks. Would anyone happen to know the source for this? Is this recitation intended to replace the midnight recitation, or is it simply in addition to it? Is the text, structure, and/or surrounding customs qualitatively distinct, in any way, from that of the midnight recitation?

Comment: וחסידים ואנשי
מעשה נוהגים לומר "תיקון חצות" אחר חצות היום בימי בין המצרים. (חצות היום, היינו,
שמחלקים את הלילה, מהשקיעה עד הזריחה לשתיים, והנקודה האמצעית, היא "חצות"
הלילה, מלשון "מחצית", ובאותה השעה ביום, הוא זמן חצות היום. ובהרבה לוחות שנה
מופיעה זמן חצות היום, או חצות הלילה, שהוא שווה לזמן חצות היום), ואומרים "תיקון
רחל" שבו פסוקים של בכי וצער על חורבן בית המקדש, ומנהג זה הוא מנהג ותיקין,
והביאו מרן החיד"א בספרו מורה באצבע, וכתב שכן נהגו בארץ ישראל על פי דברי רבינו
האר"י ז"ל, וכן כתב עוד בספרו שו"ת יוסף אומץ. וכתב שנוהגים לומר "תקון רחל", משום
שתקון רחל מיוסד על בכיה ומספד על חורבן הבית.

Comment: http://www.halachayomit.co.il/Print.asp?HalachaID=271

Comment: הימים שבין שבעה עשר בתמוז לבין תשעה באב, נקראים ימי "בין המצרים" על שם
הפסוק (במגילת איכה פרק א פסוק ג) "כל רודפיה השיגוה בין המצרים", ואמרו רבותינו
זכרונם לברכה, שאלו הימים שבין שבעה עשר בתמוז לתשעה באב, שבהם נכנסו
האויבים לירושלים עיר קדשנו ותפארתנו, ופרעו פרעות בישראל, עד יום תשעה באב
שבו החריבו את בית המקדש בעוונות הרבים, ומאז ועד היום עם ישראל אינו יושב
בטח, ותמיד קמים עליו אויבים מבית ומחוץ, ואף על פי שזכינו תהלות לאל עליון, לחזור
לארץ קדשינו בצורה חופשית, עדיין לא זכינו לגאולה שלימה, כי בית חיינו חרב, ואומות
העולם מציקות לעם ישראל יום יום, והצרות תוכפות יותר ויותר, ועל הכל מבחינה

Comment: Pinchas139, thanks for bringing your interesting (and timely) question to Mi Yodeya, and welcome to the site! Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Comment: I swear that I just saw something about this in the Netai Gavriel Hilchos Bein Hametzarim this past shabbos.

Comment: @AdamMosheh I can bring a Sefer Torah and we can make that an official swear if you want.

Comment: @HachamGabriel - You know what I mean; it's just a common idiomatic expression in the English language.

Answer (score 2):

Its in the Ben Ish Chai Shana 1 hilchos Tisha ba'av halacha 25 where he brings such an idea.

Comment: Does he offer any more details there?